# Section not showing on print preview?

Tags: html, css, printing, preview

This is probably something simple, but the Skills section on a site I'm working on for a friend (BrianCipoletta.com) isn't displaying on print preview.

The Skills section shows up fine there, but when you click Print up top or print preview, you can just barely make out (and select the top row), but nothing else shows. I've went into the print.css and I'm still at a loss.

If anyone has a minute to take a look it would be greatly appreciated, thank you! The css files are...

http://www.briancipoletta.com/css/style.css

http://www.briancipoletta.com/css/print.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main document, give your `.container` element for the Skills section a unique id:

```
<div id="skillsContainer" class="container">
```

Then in your print CSS, add the following rule:

```
#skillsContainer {
  height: 200px;
}
```

The reason Skills wasn't showing up was because in the print view, all its children were absolutely positioned, so its height defaulted to zero.

You may also want to tweak the CSS for your `column-left`, `column-right`, and `column-center` classes as well, as in the print view they are a bit taller (at 500px) than they need to be.

Comment: Thanks so much Maximillian! Just one more thing it seems...the text in the Skills section on mobile/tablet view is a lot smaller than every other section for some reason. I've tried adding "font-size: 1.15em;" to each column alignment in style.css but it doesn't affect the mobile/tablet view and only makes it larger than the other ul li's on desktop.

Any idea? Thank you again!

Comment: I would guess your text from sections other than skills are [getting font-boosted](http://www.patrickcatanzariti.com/2013/03/font-boosting/) on mobile. I would recommend using a max-width media query to put the skills section into a single column on mobile, when you're on a tiny screen it doesn't need to be in 3 columns anyway!

Comment: All set now, thank you so much for your help Maximillian! :)

Comment: Glad I could help! If you feel I fully answered your question, don't forget to mark my answer as accepted using the gray checkmark!